# Pointer arithmetic on 64-bit

Tags: visual-c++

I'm seeing some weird behavior on a 64-bit Win 7 box in C++, Visual Studio 2010:

```
if((Event*)0 != metaData.event)
```

is true when metaData.event is 0. The debugger says metaData.event has the value of 0x000000000000000f, while (Event*)0 has the value of 0x00000000.

Where could the problem be?

Cheers,
Mihai

Comment: That condition is true when metaData.even is **different** than 0

Comment: I would prefer `if (metaData.event)` anyway.

Comment: because the if is true, although the pointer is 0.

Comment: A pointer cannot have the value 0xF on Windows. Addresses in the range 0 - 0xffff form a so called NULL-pointer assignment partition, reserved for catching null-pointer assignments. That value may either indicate an incorrect conversion from int to pointer or memory corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer is not 0 it's

```
0x0...(lots of zeros)..00f
```

which means **0xf = 15dec**.

You're thus evaluating the condition as **true** even if the pointer is (likely) invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to process the metaData when the pointer is NOT null, otherwise I'm dereferencing a null pointer. The thing is, VS seems to think the pointer is != 0 although it is 0.

Comment: Woops, didn't see that last F, sorry. I thought the compiler automatically initializes pointers to 0. I manually set them to 0 in the constructor of the metaData object and everything works now, thanks!

Comment: MSalters gave the correct answer, but after you Marco. You need to answer the question and not comment on this thread so as I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Your pointer apparently is 0xf, or fifteen. On Windows, that's not a pointer to a valid object (would be >= `0x1000`). In fact, it's almost certainly caused by adding an offset to a null pointer. In other words, you've got prior Undefined Behavior.